# Get one circle after Hough transform method

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

I use Hough transform method so I get 2 circles, how can I get just the zone of the big circle from the for loop?

```
vector<Vec3f> circles;

/// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles;
HoughCircles(openImg, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,1,67, 17,35, 80);

/// Draw the circles detected
for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
{
    Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
    int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    // circle center
    circle(openImg, center, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1, 8, 0);
    // circle outline
    circle(openImg, center, radius, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1, 4, 0);

}

/// Show your results
namedWindow("Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Hough Circle Transform Demo", openImg);
```

[image: The image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native speaker. "boucle"? (I asked dict.leo.org but this didn't help.)

Comment: @scheef boucle en french sorry , i mean loop

Comment: dict translated English bouclé as German Bouclé. This was not very much enlighting. :-) So, is the answer of floydheld what you was looking for? (I understand it that size of circle is proportional to radius according to A = Pi r² (when size means area) or d = 2r (when size is diameter). Hence, the circle with max. radius is the circle with biggest size.) Could you elaborate what you mean with _zone of the big circle_? (You may [edit] your question - it's below of the tags.)

Comment: @Scheff for all the image i want just the area of the big circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of opencv states:

> circles – Output vector of found circles. Each vector is encoded as a 3-element floating-point vector (x, y, radius)

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/de5/tutorial_js_houghcircles.html

You are reading the radius (`int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);`). That is actually the size of the circle.

So, you need to loop through your array `circles` and pick the circle with the biggest radius:

```
// remember biggest radius
float radiusBiggest = 0;
// remember the index of the biggest radius / circle
int indexBiggest = -1;
// loop through all circles
for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
{
    // get the radius
    float radius = circles[i][2];
    // check if this radius is bigger than any previous
    if (radius > radiusBiggest)
    {
        // this radius/circle is the biggest so far. remember it
        radiusBiggest = radius;
        indexBiggest = i;
    }
}
// if we found a circle then draw it
if (indexBiggest != -1)
{
    Point center(cvRound(circles[indexBiggest][0]), cvRound(circles[indexBiggest][1]));
    int radius = cvRound(circles[indexBiggest][2]);
    // circle center
    circle(openImg, center, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1, 8, 0);
    // circle outline
    circle(openImg, center, radius, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1, 4, 0);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could edit in the link to doc. where you cited from.

Comment: @floydheld i don't understand how to do the loop ?

Comment: @YasmineMrd Was it helpful? did I answer your question? Please be kind and mark answer or vote?